# Bounty Question: Issue is resolved I still have no answer

Tags: discussion

So I have a question that has a bounty (250 reputation). I have done somethings and things have gotten resolved. But I don't understand fully how it fixed things. So I can't post a answer cause I don't know and none of the answers I had read so far help resolve the issue(there are some new answers, I sadly didn't get to try) I am not sure what to do here and I don't want to be unfair. I have upvoted each question I think is going in the right direction but I an not 100% sure. Any ideas?

[Link to Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954994/sql-specified-cast-is-not-valid)

Comment: Are there any answers that helped you find the solution, even if those weren't in fact the full solution?

Comment: Yes they did help

Comment: Then maybe one of them is worthy of the bounty? No?

Comment: Yes that's what I ended up doing see my answer

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did, I found the closest one that I thought it was and gave the bounty. It help me to know that I can't get that bounty back this is a very smart thing to do. I also answered my own question and marked it as the answer so if someone else had the same issue they could see what I found and use the same answer.

Comment: Nice balance between identifying the solution and rewarding those who helped you. +1

Answer (score 2):

You could post an answer to your own question. Even if you don't know exactly how it was fixed, it could be a hint to other people. If no answer helped, then just don't accept any answer.

Comment: if I don't know what do I put as a answer LOL!

Comment: @MicahArmantrout just explain the things that you changed, and that somehow one of them fixed the problem.

Comment: This is probably the most constructive way for the entire community. If you award a bounty to an answer that you think might be right, future readers who have the same problem as you will try that answer without getting anywhere.